# Want to Remove Frame of google translator

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I want to remove top frame using google Language Translation link ( http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&sl=es&tl=en&u=http://www.yahoo.com/ )....
after inserting site name and language option (Translate from:.. Translate INTO:)

Answer (score 0):

Check the instructions at [How to remove Google Translate Top Frame](http://www.farneville.com/2010/04/how-to-remove-google-translate-top-frame.html)